# How to encode/escape unicode text in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode

How can I create unicode entities out of python3 string objects?

Having `smt _ 1 #`, I want to generate `smt%20_%201%20%23`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `quote` from `urllib.parse`:

```
>>> from urrlib.parse import quote
>>> quote('smt _ 1 #')
'smt%20_%201%20%23'
```

Since you aren't dealing with a url, you don't seem to need to specify any safe characters. If you'd also require `/` to be escaped, pass `safe=''` to `quote`.